# Как посчитать weekday avarage?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Датасет https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HVPWEi6AknmOVBPWheizOG9oI225C3-C/view?usp=sharing
По примеру статьи https://habr.com/ru/company/ods/blog/327242/

```
import sys
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
from tqdm import tqdm

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error

import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import statsmodels.tsa.api as smt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import scipy.stats as scs
from scipy.optimize import minimize

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def code_mean(data, cat_feature, real_feature):
    """
    Возвращает словарь, где ключами являются уникальные категории признака cat_feature, 
    а значениями - средние по real_feature
    """
return dict(data.groupby(cat_feature)[real_feature].mean())

dataset = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/coursera/hour_online.csv')
data = dataset.copy()
data.columns = ["Time","y"]
data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Time'])
data["hour"] = data['Time'].dt.hour
data["weekday"] = data['Time'].dt.weekday
data['is_weekend'] = data.weekday.isin([5,6])*1
data.head()
lag_start=5 
lag_end=20
test_size=0.15

test_index = int(len(data.y)*(1-test_size))
for i in range(lag_start, lag_end):
    data["lag_{}".format(i)] = data.y.shift(i)
data['weekday_average'] = map(code_mean(data[:test_index], 'weekday', "y").get, data.weekday)
data["hour_average"] = map(code_mean(data[:test_index], 'hour', "y").get, data.hour)
data.drop(["hour", "weekday"], axis=1, inplace=True)

data = data.dropna()
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
X_train = data.loc[:test_index].drop(["y"], axis=1)
y_train = data.loc[:test_index]["y"]
X_test = data.loc[test_index:].drop(["y"], axis=1)
y_test = data.loc[test_index:]["y"]
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
X_train = X_train.fillna(0)
X_test = X_test.fillna(0)
```

> TypeError: invalid type promotion

```
data['weekday_average'] = map(code_mean(data[:test_index], 'weekday', "y").get, data.weekday)
data["hour_average"] = map(code_mean(data[:test_index], 'hour', "y").get, data.hour)
```

Возвращают объект map, LinearRegression с таким работать не умеет. Как сделать отдельные колонки weekday_average_1 (среднее значение для дня 1), weekday_average_12(среднее значение для дня 2), и т. д.?

Comment: Судя по приведенному тут скрипту у  вам  удалось решить предыдущую проблему. Я рад за вас.

Comment: вы забыли привести в вопросе определение функции `code_mean()`...

Comment: добавила code_mean()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [27]: data['weekday_average'] = data.groupby("weekday")["y"].transform("mean")

In [28]: data["hour_average"] = data.groupby("hour")["y"].transform("mean")

In [29]: data
Out[29]:
                    Time      y  hour  weekday  is_weekend  ...   lag_17   lag_18   lag_19  weekday_average  \
0    2017-01-01 00:00:00  34002     0        6           1  ...      NaN      NaN      NaN     43392.143603
1    2017-01-01 01:00:00  37947     1        6           1  ...      NaN      NaN      NaN     43392.143603
2    2017-01-01 02:00:00  41517     2        6           1  ...      NaN      NaN      NaN     43392.143603
3    2017-01-01 03:00:00  44476     3        6           1  ...      NaN      NaN      NaN     43392.143603
4    2017-01-01 04:00:00  46234     4        6           1  ...      NaN      NaN      NaN     43392.143603
...                  ...    ...   ...      ...         ...  ...      ...      ...      ...              ...
2620 2017-04-20 05:00:00  34833     5        3           0  ...  39052.0  40959.0  41789.0     39519.035135
2621 2017-04-20 06:00:00  35932     6        3           0  ...  35257.0  39052.0  40959.0     39519.035135
2622 2017-04-20 07:00:00  38418     7        3           0  ...  30981.0  35257.0  39052.0     39519.035135
2623 2017-04-20 08:00:00  40238     8        3           0  ...  26167.0  30981.0  35257.0     39519.035135
2624 2017-04-20 09:00:00  40763     9        3           0  ...  23643.0  26167.0  30981.0     39519.035135

      hour_average
0     31559.781818
1     33213.163636
2     35790.550459
3     40264.745455
4     45419.118182
...            ...
2620  48774.745455
2621  51035.481818
2622  53838.000000
2623  55514.927273
2624  56771.663636

[2625 rows x 22 columns]
```